# How to strongly type "Current" when implementing IEnumerator

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, datarow, ienumerator

We are implementing IEnumerator and IEnumerable in our class

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       

        ParsingFile data = new ParsingFile();

        foreach (var line in data) // Calls the current, the implicit type of line is object but we want is as a DataRow
        {
            //call MoveNext
        }

        
    }

public class ParsingFile : IEnumerator , IEnumerable 
{

    object IEnumerator.Current //need the object to be of type DataRow to avoid casting in foreach
    {
       //return a DataRow
    }


    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }


    public bool MoveNext()
    {
    //Do something
    }

}
```

The return type of current is object but want to explicitly return DataRow. Please let us know what will be the approach to achieve this?

Comment: You'd need to implement `IEnumerable<T>` rather than just `IEnumerable`. Is there a reason you're implementing it yourself though? That's rarely necessary (or a good idea).

Comment: Also, don't blindly `return this` from `GetEnumerator()`: each time a consumer calls this, you need to return a new enumerator which will start enumerating from the beginning of the sequence. It is possible to optimize here and return `this` only for the *first* call to `GetEnumerator()`, and to return a new instance on subsequent calls (Linq does this), but to start with it's safter to have separate `Enumerator` and `Enumerable` classes

Answer (score 2):

Quite honestly, unless you have *very* particular requirements, you're better off using an iterator block here, i.e. you just write:

```cs
public class ParsingFile : IEnumerable<DataRow>
{
    // use an iterator block for the typed API
    public IEnumerator<DataRow> GetEnumerator()
    {
        //Do something that involves, perhaps in a loop 
        // yield return someValue;
        // and/or
        // yield break;
    }

    // use explicit implementation for the untyped API
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

You absolutely *can* implement your own strong-typed enumerator, which may (although doesn't strictly need to) mean implementing `IEnumerator<T>`, but there are a lot of gotchas (such as allowing independent concurrent enumeration) that make it *safer* to let the compiler do the hard work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implementing an `IEnumerator`, which it's interface specifies that current is an object, you have to implement `IEnumerator<T>`

```
public class ParsingFile : IEnumerator<DataRow>
{
    public DataRow Current { get; }

    // rest of code ommited for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by jon skeet, implement `IEnumerable<DataRow>` or `IEnumerator<DataRow>` instead.

I would suggest to never implement both `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable` by the same class. Consider the following:

```
  var myParsingFile = ...
  var dr1 = myParsingFile.First();
  var dr2 = myParsingFile.First();
```

In your case the dr1 and dr2 would be different objects, and that is just very confusing.

You may also lookinto [iterator blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) for an easier way to make enumerators.